# Как правильно спозиционизровать элементы?

Tags: html, css

Как спозиционировать блок с расписанием и кнопкой, чтобы они смотрелись, как в макете? Пробовал через *flex*, но получилось плохо.
Так же, не уверен, следует ли задавать ширину и высоту блоку `.info`? Не аукнется ли это при адаптиве?

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Light', arial;
}

.wrapper {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}

/*section main*/
section {
  height: 100vh;
}

section.main {
  margin-left: 300px;
  background: #5b5858 url(../img/bg.jpg) center no-repeat;
}

.info {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.info-text h2 {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', arial;
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 56px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #f0f0f0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.info-text p {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', arial;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 56px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #f0f0f0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.info-button {
  background-color: #b36060;
  width: 208px;
  height: 43px;
}

/*sidebar*/
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 310px;
  background: #5b5858 url(../img/menu_bg.jpg) center no-repeat;
}

.sidebar .wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.logo {
  width: 245px;
  height: 76px;
  border: 3px solid rgba(197, 120, 64, 0.65);
  text-align: center;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.logo h1 {
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 44px;
  line-height: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #f4f4f4;
}

.logo span {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-15%, 80%);
  transform: translate(-15%, 80%);
  background: url(../img/menu_bg.jpg);
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  padding: 0 5px;
  font-size: 14.2px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  line-height: 24px;
}

p.desc {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #aaa9a9;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.menu-main {
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}

.menu-main ul li:nth-child(2):before {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  content: '1';
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  background: url(../img/rectangle.svg) center no-repeat;
  float: right;
  margin: 3px -5px 0 0;
}

.menu-main ul li a {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 42px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #f7f7f7;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.menu-main ul li a:hover {
  color: #ff7200;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.menu-main li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #686464;
  margin-left: -30px;
}

.menu-sub ul li a {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 32px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #bdbdbd;
}

.menu-sub ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.contact a.phone {
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fefefe;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}

.contact a.request {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 28px;
  text-transform: none;
  color: #c57c40;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #c57c40;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.contact a.request:hover {
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/clear.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/adaptive.css">
  <link href="https://allfont.ru/allfont.css?fonts=open-sans-light" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://allfont.ru/allfont.css?fonts=noto-sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="//db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/7dca09e227fdfe16908cebb4244589e4?family=Georgia" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  <script src="owl.carousel.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <title>Сияние - Декор центр</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="top-content">
          <div class="logo">
            <a href="#">
              <h1>сияние</h1>
              <span>декор центр</span>
            </a>
          </div>
          <p class="desc">Интернет-магазин отделочных материалов и дизайна.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
          <div class="menu-main">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">каталог товаров</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">новости и акции</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">наши услуги</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">портфолио</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">блог</a></li>
              <li><a href="">контакты</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="menu-sub">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">О компании</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Отзывы о нас</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Доставка и оплата</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Дизайнеры</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="contact">
          <a href="tel:+78005118909" class="phone">+7 (4822) 648-080</a>
          <a href="#" class="request">Заказать звонок</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <section class="main">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="info">
            <div class="info-text">
              <h2>Декоративные покрытия</h2>
              <p>от лучших производителей</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="info-button">
            <button>Подробнее</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Как у меня:

[image]

... как надо:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: логотип и надпись - сделайте в svg, это уберёт как минимум несколько проблем, потом беритесь за слайдер ..и да в вашем случае этот самый лого не видно вообще

Comment: зачем делать в свг? И почему лго не видно, если оно видно?

Comment: у тебя не видно логотип